# Apply !important CSS style to div, not children

Tags: html, css, text-styling

I'm working in Confluence, and I'm trying to create some `CSS` styling for `UI boxes` (made up of `divs` that I can change using `!important`) without carrying through to `child divs`. Since other macros (`divs` with default styling) can be nested inside these `UI boxes`, the `!important` styles are carried through unintentionally.

To be more specific - I have a yellow `background-color` in the `div.rwui_type_note`. Inside is another `div` when a user creates a panel macro inside the `Note UI box`. The parent `div` (UI Note) styling is making the text `background` in a child `div` (Panel) yellow.

I need the `div.panel-content`to keep it's default styling as defined by Confluence, or as manually defined by a user in the macro when using the page editor.

Here is the custom CSS for the Note UI Box:

```
.rwui_type_note, .rwui_type_note p 
{
    background-color: #FFDC1E !important; /*Needs to be important to override defaults*/
    color: black!important;
}
```

Here is how Confluence creates the `HTML` when the a white bg panel is created inside a Note UI box:

```
<div class="rwui_text_box rwui_text_small  rwui_type_note  rwui_id_caebfd70-f9c3-489b-9f95-c01c1aa13f36 ">
    <span class="rwui_icon rwui_iconfont_note"></span>
    <span class="rwui_content rwui_body rwui_has_icon ">
        <p>Text in a Note UI Box</p>
        <div class="panel" style="background-color: white;border-color: orange;border-width: 1px;">
            <div class="panelContent" style="background-color: white;">
                <p>Text in a Panel - user set to white background</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

Here is what it looks like:
[Screenshot - UI Box with Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/la1Rr.png)

Comment: If you use `!important` you're [probably doing it wrong](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/).

Comment: Do you have access to change the HTML?

Comment: @GolezTrol Have you ever used Jquery mobile?

Comment: IIRC, CSS has a "direct descendant" operator: `.parent > .directChild` that will not carry over to the target's children. Can you leverage that?

Comment: @user5014677 I have, and I don't anymore. If it forces you to use `!important`, it's yet another reason to throw it in the bin.

Comment: @GolezTrol - I wish it worked without it, but I'm fighting the default styling as defined by the macros in Confluence so the colors can be "on brand".

Comment: @TylerH - No access to final HTML, that's how the editor spits it out, and I can only affect the CSS of the space for other users to edit.

Comment: @mingos - that didn't seem to work no matter which divs I used as parent/children. I wish it would have, that would make things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your goal correct, you can do it by inheriting parent `background-color` property

```css
.rwui_type_note,
.rwui_type_note p {
  background-color: #FFDC1E !important;
  /*Needs to be important to override defaults*/
  color: black !important;
}

.panelContent p {
  background-color: inherit !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="rwui_text_box rwui_text_small  rwui_type_note  rwui_id_caebfd70-f9c3-489b-9f95-c01c1aa13f36 ">
  <span class="rwui_icon rwui_iconfont_note"></span>
  <span class="rwui_content rwui_body rwui_has_icon ">
        <p>Text in a Note UI Box</p>
        <div class="panel" style="background-color: white;border-color: orange;border-width: 1px;">
            <div class="panelContent" style="background-color: white;">
                <p>Text in a Panel - user set to white background</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: YES!

I tried inherit a few different ways, but missed adding !important to it, and that made all the difference.

Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `>` for it. I think this will solve your problem.

```
.rwui_type_note, .rwui_body > p {
background-color: #FFDC1E!important; /*Needs to be important to override defaults*/
color: black!important;}
```

Another recommendation is that don't use block elements in an inline element.